# Memory layout of a C program, why heap is also there

Tags: c, linux, memory-layout

My own imaginary memory layout is like this:

```
High Addresses                                        ---------------------------
----------------                                      | A shared "heap" that is |
|    Stack     |    ptr_var points to somewhere       | transparently managed   |
|              |    inside a common shared heap       | by the OS and the only  |
|  *ptr_var    | -----------------------------------> | limit is the computer's |
|              |                                      | available memory. When  |
----------------                                      | needed, my prog. calls  |
| [Free space] |                                      | malloc(), OS does       |
----------------                                      | bookkeeping and hands   |                               
| Static Data  |                                      | over the first addr. of |   
----------------                                      | a chunk of memory from  |
|    Code      |                                      | the "heap"              |
----------------                                      ---------------------------  
 Low Adresses
```

But in reality, every one uses the below to represent the memory layout (ICYW: the difference between the above and below illustrations is the the above one does not have a Heap section in the program's memory space):

```
High Addresses
----------------
|    Stack     |
----------------
| [Free space] |
----------------
|     Heap     | --> Key different from the 1st diagram: there is a Heap section!
----------------
| Static Data  |
----------------
|    Code      |
----------------
 Low Adresses
```

My confusion is about the Heap section. Given the 2nd diagram, does it mean that the size of heap of the program is also limited by the memory layout?

The usual idea is that, `malloc()` only returns NULL when the OS does not have enough memory to hand over to my program. But if the layout is exactly like the 2nd diagram, how is it possible for the program to `malloc()` a lot of memory? (Say on a computer with 16GB available memory, I `malloc()` 15.9GB of them successfully). What will be the size of the Heap section?

```
High Addresses
--------------------------
|    Stack               |
| ptr1* = malloc(15.9GB) | ------------┑
--------------------------             |
|    [Free space]        |             |
--------------------------             | --> ptr1 points to some address in it's own Heap?
|                        |             |
|                        | <-----------┘
|    Heap                | 
|                        | ----------------> What is the size of Heap section? >=15.9GB?
|                        | 
--------------------------
| Static Data            |
--------------------------
|    Code                |
--------------------------
 Low Adresses
```

Comment: Actually, on modern systems neither layout is correct. With virtual memory the operating systems can arrange the sections in any order, at any location, it wants.

Comment: Also: look up the term "ASLR".

Comment: emmm @Someprogrammerdude then what was the vanilla case, say, 20 years/30 years ago?

Comment: @Lundin I think ASLR is transparently managed by OS--let's say I disabled ASLR?

Comment: Your tags mention Linux, you can look at the memory layout of a process by `cat /proc/<pid>/maps` (where pid is the number of the process). If I look at the layout of something, I can see that there is 45 TB between the heap and the next other thing (I don't have that much physical memory installed, this is just virtual address space).

Comment: @D.J.Elkind When enabled, it gives you different offsets each time, within a certain address range.

Comment: *"`The usual idea is that, malloc() only returns NULL when the OS does not have enough memory to hand over to my program.`"* No, Linux does not allocate any memory when you call `malloc` and the system assumes that you have enough memory. It will be allocated when you actually touch this memory.

Comment: @0___________ I actually think my wording avoids what you try to refute: I said `malloc()` returns NULL if OS doesnt have enough memory to hand over, but I do NOT say OS will immediately hand over the memory to my program if there IS enough memory. So let say there are two programs, the 1st program `malloc()`ed all the available memory, the OS will do book keeping, before the memory is actually handed over to 1st program. Then the 2nd program try `malloc()` a lot of memory, it gets a `NULL` as OS does not have enough memory for it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What and where are the stack and heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap)

Comment: Hi @Ôrel if possible I would request you not to close my question based on this. I believe the link is more of an overview and my question is more detailed. You can say that my question can serve as a more detailed follow-up question after the question in your link is satisfactorily answered.

Comment: @SupportUkraine I am not asking "whether", but HOW, given the memory layout, can it support 16G. If the heap is a part of my program's memory space (as shown in the 2nd diagram), how can be the heap be shared with other programs.

Comment: The real problem is not the layout of the virtual memory (which is defined in every OS) but the maximum size of these regions. The point you seem to miss is the virtual memory system (the mapping from your adresses to hardware addresses).

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I suppose you mean to say that the Heap section in my program's private memory space is a "dummy" one? it is as large as the real "heap" outside my program and it is only mapped to my program's memory space as if my program owns the entirety of it? (but actually it is shared and managed by OS?)

Comment: @SupportUkraine emmm let me ask you one thing...do you think you understand what I am asking in the question?..

Comment: @SupportUkraine well perhaps you just ignore all the comments, I think the original post has all the information and it contains a concrete question: "What will be the size of the Heap section?" Will it be ~15.9GB?

Comment: @D.J.Elkind You have a virtual memory up to 2^64 bytes, shared across mostly stack and heap. In general stack goes downward from high adresses (the converse for the heap). Now there is a mapping from that virtual space to the physical one (this includes RAM but also disk space), so the real limit is that: the physical available space which alas is shared across different processes on your machine. OS always try to give as much as you need, but real conditions may alter this of course.

Answer (score 4):

> … the only limit is the computer's available memory…

That is not the limit. A general-purpose multi-user computer system uses virtual memory. With virtual memory, each process has its own address space: It uses addresses that are, essentially, numbers in a designed address space. Each time an instruction is executed that accesses memory, the computer processor translates the virtual memory address to a physical memory address.

This means the program must have physical memory for a virtual address **at the moment an instruction using the address is executed.** At other times, the virtual address does not have to be mapped to actual physical memory.

The operating system manages physical memory and gives the processor information about which virtual addresses in which processes are mapped to which physical addresses. When the processor executes an instruction that uses memory, it uses that mapping information to figure out the physical address. If no physical memory is mapped for the requested virtual address, the processor stops execution of the process and informs the operating system about this. Then the operating system maps physical memory for the virtual address and tells the processor to restart the process. (This may involve unmapping other physical memory or making other changes, and, if the operating system cannot satisfy the request, it may terminate the process.)

To make physical memory available for a process, the operating system might choose some physical memory that is already in use and write its contents to a disk. Later, when the contents of that memory are needed again, the operating system will read it back into physical memory. This is called swapping. Also, some parts of memory might have originated as read-only data already stored in files on disk, such as parts of executable files. In this case, the operating system does not need to write the contents of memory to disk to save it, because it is already on disk. It merely needs to know that it can read it back later from the original file.

In this way, by swapping data in and out of memory, the operating system can make a process work even if the process uses more virtual memory than the amount of physical memory the system has.

> Given the 2nd diagram, does it mean that the size of heap of the program is also limited by the memory layout?

The amount of virtual memory a process can have is limited by the virtual address space. If you are designing the layout of data in the virtual address space and you designate certain regions for stack and certain regions for static data, then you reduce the amount of memory available for other purposes because those regions are not available for other purposes.

One might put the static data at the “bottom” of the address space (at addresses starting near zero) and the stack at the “top” of the address space (near high-value addresses), leaving the middle of the address space for dynamically allocated memory. With today’s large address spaces, that leaves plenty of room for dynamically allocated memory.

Additionally, memory use is complicated by dynamically loading libraries and multithreading, which can bring new static data into a process after it has already started executing and can create new stacks. However, there is no theoretical reason why these various types of data in a process cannot be interleaved. When a process wants to request new memory mappings for static data, stack space, or dynamically allocated memory, it can ask the operating system for a block of memory, and the operating system can fit it into the address space anywhere there is an unused segment. (I am not familiar with all the details of today’s various program loaders and arrangements for managing address space, so I do not assert that any particular systems do or do not do this.)

Comment: For "with virtual memory, each process has its own address space", what is the size of the address space of one program? is this something decided by OS? Let's say my computer has 8GB physical memory in total and no swap space, is the address space of my program 8GB too?

Comment: @SupportUkraine well if virtual address space is 128TiB, what is the maximum possible size of my call stack? What is my call stack's starting and ending address in the virtual address space?

Comment: @D.J.Elkind: Your maximum stack size is set by the program loader, which puts a page deliberately marked unreadable at the end of the space it sets, so that accessing that page will cause a trap. The size it uses for that is set in the executable file by the linker, which uses a default (1 MiB Windows, 2 MiB Linux, 8 MiB macOS, if I recall correctly) unless you request a different size. While we could easily allow much larger stacks, limiting the size is a useful mechanism to catch bugs. So it is a chosen limit, not an architectural limit.

Comment: @EricPostpischil emmm...perhaps let me put it this way. For the 2nd diagram in my original post, is it an illustration of the layout of the virtual memory space? If I just search "memory layout" in Google, it is everywhere, but I am not sure if it is meant to illustrate the layout of the virtual memory space.

Comment: @SupportUkraine so the lowest address is always `0x0000 0000 0000` and highest address is always `0x8000 0000 0000` (i.e., (2^10)^4 * 128) given the virtual memory space is 128TiB?